# Why does my image wiggle on hover?

Tags: hover, css-transitions, shake

Can anyone help me understand why the videos image (but not the play icons) at http://www.alternativeradio.org/pages/free-downloads wiggle up a pixel then down a pixel when I mouseover, then again when I mouseout? The effect is slower on Firefox, so it probably has something to do with CSS transitions.

Comment: My guess would be a border appearing or disappearing in a :hover rule--either on the image or the link. I can't reproduce the problem in Chrome.

Comment: Chrome is where I first noticed the effect. I'm using the latest version (21.0.1180.79) on a 27" iMac. There are no borders on the anchor, image, or contained span. I think it's a bug with opacity and transitions, because if I disable either, the jiggly wiggly is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was having the same issue with an image gallery using CSS filters and transitions. Got rid of the unwanted wiggle through help from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16209237)

Comment: I'm not having the issue anymore, but thank you! @RadimKöhler this answer does not link to an external site, it links to a helpful answer.